# Setuptools with easy_install does not copy over the source to /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages

Tags: python, setuptools

I have created an egg distribution. The code for setup.py and the associated configuration params are in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924296/excluding-source-files-from-built-rpm-distribution-with-setuptool).

Now when I run `easy_install <Engine-1.0.0.egg>` I only see the Engine-1.0.0.egg-info file getting copied over, not the included files in Engine packages.

Any pointer to what I am missing here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check your previous question, I put there many tips how to resolve it. In a way, you are here asking the same question, do not do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excluding source files from built rpm distribution with setuptool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924296/excluding-source-files-from-built-rpm-distribution-with-setuptool)